# Pseudo-tty with Fig/Docker container

Tags: docker, fig

I need pseudo-tty and keep stdin open even if I am not attached to the container. 
In docker I can use this: `docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash`

If I use this in fig:

```
test:
  image: ubuntu:14.04
  command: /bin/bash
```

Then I can't connect to the running docker container. Any idea?

Comment: what fig command are you using ? In your case you want to use `fig run test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With docker 1.3, there is a new command [`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/). This allows you to enter a running docker:

```
docker exec -it <container-id> bash
```

For older version of docker I would use the [nsenter](https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter), a tool to connect to a running docker container.